# Why this iteration summation is wrong when I calculate it?

Tags: calculus, summation, arithmetic, real-numbers, summation-method

$V_n = 3^{n}$

I need to calculate its summation where

$S = (V_0)^{2} + (V_1)^{2} + ... + (V_{n-1})^2 $

Obviously, you can just put a new iteration $(W_n)$ where $W_n = (V_n)^{2}$ You find it $W_n = 9^{n}$ and then in the end you find

$S = (9^{n} - 1) / 8$

But when I tried putting it like this

$S = 3^{2(0)} + 3^{2(1)} + ... + 3^{2(n-1)}$

I find $S = (3^{2n-1} - 1) / 2$

And if you put $n = 1$ or $n = 0$ in both summations we found, you clearly don't find the same value which means the second one is probably wrong but I don't understand why. It should be the same.

Comment: In fact you miss terms, if you add odd powers you get $S+3S=\frac{3^{2n}-1}2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $(3^{2n-1}-1)/2$ would be $3^0+3^1+\cdots+3^{2n-2}$, whereas $S$ lacks the odd-exponent terms. As @zwim notes, the even terms are $S$ and the odd ones are $3S$, and their sum is $4S$. Note $4=(3^2-1)/(3-1)$.

Comment: I don't think I get it. I thought the summation formula was the same one in every case.

Comment: @TechnoKnight $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}ar^k=a\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$ is always right, but your mistake was in what you thought each parameter was.

Comment: But I don't get it. $n$ should be equal to 2n-2 + (0) + 1 which is $2n-1$ and $r$ is $3$ so why my summation on the second case is wrong?

Comment: @TechnoKnight $n$ is the number of terms, $r$ is the ratio of two successive terms, and $a$ is the first term. For $3^0+3^1+3^2+...+3^9$ you would have $(a,r,n)=(1,3,10)$, but for $3^0+3^2+3^4+...+3^8$ with only even exponents you have $(a,r,n)=(1,3^2,5)$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Ooooh, I got it. It seems that I got it all wrong.

Comment: Thanks for everyone!